# linux directory location best practices for software development

Tags: directory, visual-studio-code, projects

I am new to linux (ubuntu) and am tasked to develop web pages using vscode. What would be the ideal location for me to keep my project directories? I don't want to be illogical or pollute a file system convention I don't know about.

Answer (score 4):

Personal projects all belong in the `/home/` directory. When you're ready to test you'll symlink to the directroy you host from. When you're done with the project you'll have to decide where the best "permanent" location is. See the [File System Hierarchy Standard](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) for details.

Comment: sounds reasonable. should I create  a directory like /home/projects and create sub folders for each project? Looking at the File System Hierarchy Standard is seems almost like var would be the proper place.Variable data, such as logs, databases, websites, and temporary spool (e-mail..) files

Comment: You can make whatever directory structure you need. The home directory is kind of like the "my documents" folder of windows in the way it is used

Comment: sounds good and I am satisfied. Alex how do I give you some kind of up vote? Seems like a big deal here but don't see any means to give an atta boy.

Answer (score 0):

You can automount external drive and use that drive to save your projects.

Answer (score 0):

According the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) I recommend create a directory inside

`/var/lib/`

with the name of the application, just like this:

`/var/lib/my-app`